# If S is a subset of the positive real numbers whose members obey "addition" by A⊕B=1/2AB (where all A,B ∈ S), how do I show this operation is closed?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I've already shown the associativity, commutativity, additive identity, and additive inverse for the operation, but I'm confused about demonstrating closure.

I know the multiplication of any two real numbers produces a real number, so AB will produce a positive real number, which seems like it would be in S, but how do I know that number will always be in S? S is defined as a SUBset of the real numbers (IE, apparently not ALL real numbers?), so what exactly are the bounds of that? Can two elements, A,B be multiplied and exceed the 'boundaries' of S? 
If no, why not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't. You can choose a subset of the positive reals that is not closed under that operation. For example, the set {1}.

Comment: I don't know what this is for, but you can turn things on its head and define $S$ as a set in which your "addition" operation is closed. Then you have to demonstrate that at least one such set $S$ exists. Otherwise you have hit a dead end, as @mmesser314 's comment (which should really be an answer) shows.

Comment: I ended up saying,

Comment: Sorry, The prof's question specifically asks "why is the operation (⊕) closed?" so he definitely seems to think it is (or expects us to ignore certain inconsistencies with that assertion). I ended up saying "since A ∈ S and B ∈ S, and multiplication (and addition) are closed binary operations which map any two elements of a given set to itself through S × S → S, the operation ⊕ in A⊕B=1/2AB is closed".  My confidence in that answer is not 100%, though.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: Then your professor had a specific set in mind. You would need to show that for any two members of that set, the results is also in the set.